# Android RadioGroup OnCheckedChangeListener

Tags: android, checkbox, listener, android-radiogroup

I have an Activity which implements both `Checkbox.OnCheckedChangeListener` and `RadioGroup.OnCheckedChangeListener` The groups are both dynamically generated and passed the same `Activity` as the `listener`.

However, when I click on a RadioGroup, the `RadioGroup.OnCheckChangeListener` is completely ignored but here's where it gets weird. It triggers `CheckBox.OnCheckChangeListener`! I tried casting the activity to the RadioGroup listener before passing it, but RadioGroup cannot even accept it, only the CheckBox listener gets through.

```
@Override
        public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton buttonView, boolean isChecked) {
            if(subquestion.getQuestionType().equals("MULTIPLE_CHOICE_MULTI_ANSWER")) {
                String selected = buttonView.getText().toString();
                if (subquestion.getAnswer().getDataList() != null) {
                    Answer answer = subquestion.getAnswer();
                    ArrayList<String> checked = answer.getDataList();
                    if (checked.contains(selected)) {
                        checked.remove(selected);
                        Log.d("Checkbox" + buttonView.getId(), "unchecked");
                    } else {
                        checked.add(selected);
                        Log.d("Checkbox" + buttonView.getId(), "checked");
                    }
                } else {
                    ArrayList<String> checked = new ArrayList<String>();
                    checked.add(selected);
                    subquestion.getAnswer().setDataList(checked);
                    Log.d("Checkbox" + buttonView.getId(), "checked");
                }
            }
            if(subquestion.getQuestionType().equals("MULTIPLE_CHOICE_SINGLE_ANSWER")) {
                RadioGroup group = buttonView; //CAN'T BE DONE
                String selected = group.getFocusedChild().getId() + "";
                subquestion.getAnswer().setData(selected);
                Log.d("Radiobutton " + selected + group.getFocusedChild().getId(), "selected");
            }
        }

        @Override
        public void onCheckedChanged(RadioGroup group, int checkedId) {
           //This does NOTHING, can't even be passed to the RadioGroup as a listener
        }
```

How do I get the RadioGroup from the buttonView? I generate everything in code and it's different every time so there are no static id's to determine what's clicked. I pass an id to the radiobuttons to let me know which is which but I can't get to it like this.

It works perfectly for the checkboxes, it's just that Android seems to throw the wrong event and uses the wrong event handler for RadioGroup.

Thank you for reading!

Comment: did you tried setting android:focusable="false"
        android:focusableInTouchMode="false"
to radioGroup ?

Answer (score 2):

Call this method for RadioGroup.OnCheckChangeListener and pass RadioGroup as argument

```
public void onRadioChangeListener(RadioGroup radioGroup){

    radioGroup.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new OnCheckedChangeListener() {
        @Override
        public void onCheckedChanged(RadioGroup group, int checkedId) {
            // write your code here
        }
    });
}
```

Comment: [Creating leaks](http://www.androiddesignpatterns.com/2013/01/inner-class-handler-memory-leak.html) You should not be doing that anywhere as it causes major leaks. For now I pass whether it's a checkbox or a radiogroup outside of everything by specifying the type of group in a separate class which holds the data to generate the groups with and pass that to the activity to see what's what. Quite an ugly hack but functional enough.

Comment: As you said that your onCheckedChangeListener is not working for RadioGroup

Comment: It passes the event to the wrong onCheckedChangeListener. The listener itself works fine.